# Posting a Json Object to Restful Web Service

Tags: java, android, rest, web, put

I have to post the comment of a user to a web service. However I fail.

I have a AsyncTask class in which I do the following :

```
@Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

        JSONObject jsobj = null;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;

        String urlStr = params[0];
        String message = params[2];
        String name = params[1];

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlStr);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.connect();


            jsobj.put("name", name);
            jsobj.put("text", message);
            jsobj.put("id", news_id);

            DataOutputStream writer
                    = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            writer.writeBytes(jsobj.toString());
            writer.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();


        }


 return jsobj;
    }
```

In initialization I do the following:

```
DataTask4 tsk = new DataTask4();

tsk.execute("http://94.138.207.51:8080/NewsApp/service/news/savecomment",commentowner,message)
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong but seems that I can put the json object correctly to the web-service.

Comment: What exactly fails? Could you give like an error message or a stack trace?

Comment: It keeps the progress bar downloading but nothing is put to the server.

Comment: I see you initalise a JSONObject called jsonobj but that you do not fill (because you fill another one) it and return it at the end.

Comment: Yeah I fixed that thank you but now the app crashes...

Comment: Try using Retrofit library http://square.github.io/retrofit/ - will make your life much simpler - removes the need to mess with connections and JSONObjects

Comment: @ayt_cem post the stacktrace

Comment: The use of DataOutputStream looks suspicious to me.